# Why am I getting 'Braintree/BTUICTAControl.h' file not found error on Braintree manual integration?

Tags: ios, xcode, braintree

I get the following build error after implementing step number four "Add the Braintree SDK code to project" from the [Manual Integration Without CocoaPods](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/master/Docs/Manual%20Integration.md) guide.

> braintree_ios/Braintree/UI/Braintree-Payments-UI.h:3:9: 'Braintree/BTUICTAControl.h' file not found

### Tested in

- New Objective-C iOS app project.
- In Xcode 6.1 (6A1042b) and 6.3 (6D543q)

How can I fix this build error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on the Braintree iOS SDK.

I believe using the name `Braintree` instead of `Braintree SDK` for the framework target name will resolve this particular issue. I recently [updated the manual docs](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/commit/72ce3a803067bcb3d20455437859f48d2ecec799) accordingly.

We recommend that you integrate using CocoaPods if at all possible, as it handles all this complexity for you.

Note also that I've responded on [the issue you posted on GitHub](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/issues/110). Let's resolve this there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually downloading the zip file and not using git?
Try following the second bullet point from the first step.

Comment: I tried from scratch by by downloading the braintree instead of using git. Unfortunately I get the same build error. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I don't want to be a bringer of bad news. But after downloading and trying it myself, I found there was something wrong with build paths. Changing the import statements to be relative (using " ") rather < > helped remedy it. Either, manually fix the import or try asking Braintree for an already compiled Library. Sorry and good luck.